# Incorrect time zone when script is run remotely

Tags: c#

I have a C# script in SSIS that is hosted on a server in NY.  When I exec the job directly (RDP to server, F5 to run), I get the correct time zone info from the code below:

```
var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
GeoCodeDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
```

However, when I run the job from SQL Agent (which is hosted on another server in NY), I get the wrong time.  I have verified that both servers have the correct system time (control panel -> Date & Time)

Example of problem:

I ran the SQL Agent job today when it was 1:58 PM Eastern time, and GeoCodeDateTime was set to `2017-03-27 17:58:32.000`

Why am I getting the wrong time when executing this code from SQL Agent?

### Update

dlatikay's suggestion to output DateTime.UtcNow led me to another test, which narrows down the mystery.
The code that gets the time is compiled into a dll that I've referenced in the C# script.  So it's when the code is executed via the dll that I get the wrong time via SQL Agent.  When I get the time directly in the SSIS script task, I get the right time when executed from SQL Agent.

Comment: how exactly do you run it from agent? is the remote agent using a different user profile? is it a whole number of hours off? exactly one hour off? from yesterday to today there was a daylight savings time switch in many countries (don't know whether in US, too)

Comment: @dlatikay : The SQL Agent job is set to run Package Source as File System, with a link to the .dtsx on the server that hosts the SSIS package.  And yes, there is a different user profile, but I'm not sure how that impacts the result of time zone.  The time is 4 hours off (I expect 13:58, and I'm getting 17:58, which is 5:58pm)

Comment: Looks like something is converting to GMT as that conversion matches exactly.

Comment: What about running the code on the sql agent machine not via sql process. Just as code. With log output for UtcNow and then conversion result. What do you get? What time zone is configured? Are you using ntp?

Comment: @ilansch - I'm not able to do that due to corporate app install restrictions (I can't install anything on the server that hosts SQL).  Yes, all computers on the domain use NTP.

Comment: Currently, Eastern Standard Time should be "(UTC-04:00) Eastern Daylight Time (US & Canada)", so when you get 1:58 p.m., which is 13:58, it would imply 5:58 p.m. = 17:58 as a value of DateTime.UtcNow. Can you return the raw value of DateTime.UtcNow as an additional output? Looks like the conversion does not take place at all.

Comment: @dlatikay - I ran the job directly and got `2017-03-27 18:53:15.737` (for UtcNow), then ran it remotely and got` 2017-03-27 18:53:55.647`.  However, you gave me another idea to try.  See my question update.